# How to insert a pattern every n characters with input that may have new lines?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to use sed to insert a pattern into a file every 2000 characters. I'm using this sed command, but it doesn't work if the file has multiple lines in it, because the count resets on every new line.

Pattern: `'
 || '`

```
sed "s/.\{2000\}/&'\n || '/g" file
```

How do I make this command work with input that may or may not have new lines? I'm okay with a non-sed solution.

Here is an example inserting the pattern every 4 characters instead of 2000.

Example input:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
```

Example output:

```
aaaa'
 || 'aa
b'
 || 'bbbb'
 || 'b
```

1. Count 4 characters (4 a's), insert pattern.
2. Count 4 characters (2 a's, new line character, and 1 b), insert pattern.
3. Count 4 characters (4 b's), insert pattern.
4. Only 1 character left (1 b)

Thanks.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: With GNU sed, you may use `sed -z "s/.\{2000\}/&'\n || '/g" file`. However, newline will be counted as a separate char.

Comment: Added sample input. @WiktorStribiżew solution works perfectly but sadly my gnu sed version is 4.2.1, support for -z was added in 4.2.2.

Comment: Updated my solution.  PS you do miss a `b` in your output (should be 6 `b`)  Why do you get `aa\nb'\n` there are no 4 letter?

Comment: Can you explain what should happen on new line.  Should counting start from 0, or from the left over number from previous line?

Comment: Added an explanation for output. On new line counting should continue from the count from the previous line.

Comment: I do not understand ´2.´, why only on ´b´. Your question was `2000` character, should it then still start with one character on the new line.  Why so complicated.

Comment: Sorry @Jotne my question was with 2000, but I changed it to every 4 characters in the sample input/output section since I didn't want to put extremely long input in the post.

Comment: Various posted solutions will produce the posted expected output given the posted sample input but will handle other input differently from each other. For example try each of the solutions `echo 'aaa' | solution` and `echo 'aaa' | solution`. Your question doesn't address how to handle those and other edge cases which are the only non-trivial part of solving this problem so you should think about what the edge cases are and include sample input/output for those in your question otherwise you're likely to get a solution that works for your one sample but not for your real data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl -0777pe "s/(.{2000})/\$1'\n || '/gs" file`

- `-0777` to process entire file as one line
- `\$1` to allow reference to capture group w/o shell making it null because I have to use double quotes
- `s///gs` uses `g` to repeat more than once, and `s` to ensure `.{4}` can straddle newlines.

```
$ printf "aaaaaa\nbbbbbb\n" |  perl -0777pe "s/(.{4})/\$1'\n || '/gs"
aaaa'
 || 'aa
b'
 || 'bbbb'
 || 'b
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and only reading 4 chars into memory at a time (as opposed to reading the whole file into memory at once as some of the other solutions require):

```
$ awk -v RS='.{4}' '{printf "%s", (RT=="" ? $0 : RT "\047\n || \047")}' file
aaaa'
 || 'aa
b'
 || 'bbbb'
 || 'b
```

Comment: Nice, vs `perl -0777` or `sed -z`

Comment: or `awk -v RS=""` when there's no blank lines in the file (that approach would fail if there were) or `gawk -v RS='^$'` which I don't see in any answers so far but might be coming.

Answer (score 1):

This `gnu awk` may do:

```
echo "abcdefghijkl" | awk -v FS= -v OFS= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i>1 && i%3==1)  $i="\n ||"$i}1'
abc
 ||def
 ||ghi
 ||jkl
```

For your file, with every 1000 characters.

```
awk -v FS= -v OFS= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i>1 && i%1000==1)  $i="\n ||"$i}1' file
```

Updated solution:

```
awk -v FS= -v OFS= '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (i>1 && i%4==1)  $i="\x27\\n || \x27"$i;printf "%s\x27\\n || \x27",$0} END {print ""}' file
aaaa'\n || 'aa'\n || 'bbbb'\n || 'bb'\n || '
```

Comment: Use octal `\047` instead of hex `\x27` to represent `'`. See http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote. Also, compared to the posted expected output, that final script is missing `\nb` after the `'aa` and shows an extra `b'\n || '` at the end of the output.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the \047 tip.  The OP changed the request so many times, that I have given up to solve it.

Comment: You're welcome and yeah I had a feeling that might've been the case!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Generic approach where we can give number of characters after which you want to insert string. Using GNU `awk`'s `RS`, `FS`, `gsub` features. Tested with GNU `awk` and with only provided samples.(Ok, I just now tested for inserting NEW character after 5 characters also it worked pretty well :) )

```
awk -v noc="4" -v char="\047\n || \047" -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '{num=num==noc?(noc-1):noc;gsub(".{"num"}","&" char)} 1' Input_file
```

***Adding a non-one liner form of solution:***

```
awk -v noc="4" -v char="\047\n || \047" -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '
{
  num=num==noc?(noc-1):noc
  gsub(".{"num"}","&" char)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Output will be as follows:***

```
aaaa'
 || 'aa
b'
 || 'bbbb'
 || 'b
```

---

---

***Explanation of above code:*** Adding complete explanation of above code.

```
awk -v noc="4" -v char="\047\n || \047" -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '  ##Mentioning noc=4 for number of characters after which we want to insert new character\
                                                               ## , mentioning char variable with value which OP wants to insert. \
                                                               ##  Making RS NULL here, making FS as new line here for all lines of Input_file
{
  num=num==noc?(noc-1):noc                                     ##Creating variable num whose value is noc-1 when it is 4 and 4 when it is NOT 4.
  gsub(".{"num"}","&" char)                                    ##Using gsub function to give number of characters which need to be substitutes with new char here.
}
1                                                              ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited line of Input_file.
'  Input_file                                                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

The following sed solution will work (using four characters rather than 2000):

```
  sed "H;1h;\$!d;x;s/.\{4\}/&'\n || '/g"
```

Explanation:

- `H;1h;\$!d;x` read entire file into pattern buffer (see  [sed: read whole file into pattern space without failing on single-line input](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/182153))
- `s/.\{4\}/&'\n || '/g` add the desired text after every four characters

In bash, we need to escape the dollar sign, `\$`, because as the replace pattern contains single quotes, it is easier to use double-quotes to enclose the sed string.

**Edit:** As note by Ed Morton in a comment, rather than using double-quotes and escaping the `$`, an alternative is to use single quotes and replace each embedded single quote `'` with `'\''`, to get:

```
  sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/.\{4\}/&'\''\n || '\''/g'
```

Comment: With that approach of double quoting the script you'd also need to escape the `!` in some shells with some history options set. Always use single quotes around strings and scripts unless you **need** double quotes to avoid falling into "escaping" hell - `sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/.\{4\}/&'\''\n || '\''/g' file`. Not that I'm recommending you actually use sed for this of course.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special Linux command for splitting files by specified parameters.

Read more about `csplit` command [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucsplit.htm).